# Binding a checkbox to a model when POSTing a form

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

Here is my simple class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using XXX.Domain;

namespace XXX.WebUI.Models
{
    public class AccountRegisterModel
    {
        ..snip..

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must agree to our terms of use.")]
        public bool AcceptedTerms { get; set; }

        ..snip..
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
<div class="terms">
    <input type="checkbox" name="AcceptedTerms" value="AcceptedTerms"  />
    <img class="sim" src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/unchecked.gif")" alt="accept the terms" />
    <p>I accept the <span class="legalize">Terms of Service &amp; Privacy Policy</span> and wish to continue</p>
</div>
```

The view starts out with the checkbox not checked and using some Javascript code I use an image to create a snazzy checkbox and behind the scenes update the checkbox so the correct value is posted back.

```
$('.terms input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
```

For debugging purposes I've added a `display:block` rule to the "hidden" **actual** checkbox to see if the check is actually being ticked when I click the image and I can confirm that this is the case.

Also, using Firebug, here's the HTML that's shown when I click the image and the checkbox is ticked:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AcceptedTerms" value="AcceptedTerms">
```

When the form is posted, the value of AcceptedTerms remains false, as if the value is not being posted back to my server. Maybe the HTML is missing an attribute I'm not aware of.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What form? How are you posting it? jQuery $.ajax or something similar?

Comment: I didn't post the HTML form because it isn't relevant. It's a simple for that POSTS data, nothing with $.ajax or whatnot. :) If you need to see it let me know, but it's nothing out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AcceptedTerms" value="AcceptedTerms"  />
```

should be changed to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AcceptedTerms" value="true"  />
```

value needs to be true not AcceptedTerms.

If you use @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.AcceptedTerms)

you will see that the value is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the value you need to bind your checkbox to your view model.  I would have it like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.AcceptedTerms)
```

When your form is posted it should have the value of the checkbox ie. if it was checked (true) or not (false).